# Importing DBDUMP on 2 machines gives diff time stamps

Tags: oracle11g, timezone

I have imported same dbdump on 2 machines. When, I execute an sql, I see 2 different values.

```
select struct_doc_id, START_DATE, END_DATE from structured_doc where struct_doc_id = 1329 order by START_DATE;
```

Machine1:

```
1329    31-03-11 09:00:00.000000000 PM  01-01-16 08:59:59.999000000 PM
1329    01-04-11 12:00:00.000000000 AM  31-12-15 11:59:59.999000000 PM
```

Machine 2:

```
1329    01-04-11 12:00:00.000000000 AM  31-12-15 11:59:59.999000000 PM
1329    01-04-11 12:00:00.000000000 AM  31-12-15 11:59:59.999000000 PM
```

Also, I executed the sql:

```
select dbtimezone, sessiontimezone, systimestamp, current_timestamp 
from dual;
```

and the results on both the machines are:

Machine 1:

```
-07:00  Asia/Calcutta   09-02-16 02:15:55.422190000 AM -08:00   09-02-16 03:45:55.422204000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA
```

Machine 2:

```
-07:00  Asia/Calcutta   09-02-16 05:23:20.703408000 AM -05:00   09-02-16 03:53:20.703418000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA
```

Note: I have 2 database running on 2 different machines.

Can anyone please tell me what may be the possible reasons for the difference in the values while running first sql?

Answer (score 0):

As i can see it might be one reason for that :
 Check the datatype of the column *structured_doc* is it :
"timestamp" or "timestamp with local timezone","timestamp with timezone".

Oracle will automatically ajust the date provided, according the session's attributes of the client.
I guess you're executing the import remotely in one database, and locally in the other.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. As per get_ddl: "START_DATE" TIMESTAMP (3), "END_DATE" TIMESTAMP (3). Also, I am running import locally in both the database. Since, it is just timestamp, oracle should not internally adjust dates.

Comment: Yes Swaraj it shouldn't,
In machine 2, i am seeing the same row duplicated, are we sure it isn't an integrity issue we are facing here?
When runing impdp utility, oracle dynamically chose to do direct/conventionnal inserts(so ignore or respect constraints), according to the table complexity.
If you are using Sql Loader, are you using the same control_file?, to be more sure please verify the value of 'direct' parameters in both control_files.

Comment: There are few other columns as well in the table. I have masked them to make things simpler. I will check control files and update. Thanks once again for the interest.

Comment: let me know if you find the same values in both control_files of sqlLoader